# Upper bound of Wasserstein distance given by subvariables of codim 1

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, probability-distributions

recently I am considering the upper-bound of Wasserstain distance. Say we have random vectors $X,Y$ of dimension $n$, and let $\tilde{X}_i (\tilde{Y}_i,$ resp.) be the $(n-1)$-dim random vector of $X (Y $, resp.) discarding the $i$-th component. For example, $n=3$ and $X=(X_1,X_2,X_3)$, then $\tilde{X}_2=(X_1,X_3)$.

My question is, can we formulate an inequality of the form $W_p(X,Y) \leq \sum \limits_{i=1}^na_i W_p(\tilde{X}_i,\tilde{Y}_i)$? I know that we can formulate similar inequality by using $1$-dim marginals [refer here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37677/wasserstein-distance-in-rd-from-one-dimensional-marginals), hence I believe such inequality would hold for $(n-1)$-subvariables.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\tX{\tilde X}\newcommand\tY{\tilde Y}\newcommand\D{\overset D=}$The answer is no. E.g., suppose that $n=2$, so that $\tX_1,\tX_2,\tY_1,\tY_2$  can be identified with $X_2,X_1,Y_2,Y_1$, respectively, and the inequality in question becomes
$$W_p(X,Y)\le a_1W_p(X_2,Y_2)+a_2W_p(X_1,Y_1).\tag{1}$$
Suppose also $X_1\D Y_1$, $X_2\D Y_2$, but $X\not\D Y$, where $\D$ denotes the equality in distribution. Then the right-hand side of (1) is $0$ but the left-hand side is $>0$. So, (1) fails to hold.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is illustrative.

Comment: @YUANZhiri : So, to have a closure, are you satisfied with this answer?

Comment: honestly speaking, no. My aim is to construct an upper bound of Wasserstein distance between two distributions, by using their sub-distributions and dependence structures (like the correlation/copulas). We have formulated similar results of LOWER bounds for lots of distances like Wasserstein and chi2, and now we are interested in the UPPER bounds of Wasserstein. Should you provide any reference about it, I would be rather grateful.

Comment: @YUANZhiri : In your post, you did not mention any "dependence structures (like the correlation/copulas)". So, your question, "can we formulate an inequality of the form $W_p(X,Y) \leq \sum \limits_{i=1}^na_i W_p(\tilde{X}_i,\tilde{Y}_i)$" has been fully answered. The answer shows that such upper bounds do not exist, even if you want/need them. Do you disagree with any of these statements?

Comment: Yeah, I understand your point. BTW, I did not mention "dependence structures (like the correlation/copulas)", because for lower bound such terms would naturally appear, so I wonder whether for the upper bound similar phenomenon/structure will also appear. Anyway, I do not think there exists a general result for the upper bound. Thanks.

Comment: @YUANZhiri : All right. Now that your posted question has been fully answered and you "do not think there exists a general result for the upper bound", what about the closure? You can always ask another question with any additional conditions specified.